# How to create a customized(non-linear, not log) x-axis in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot a series data like the following, which is very uneven distributed in x axis (unit: second).
say, here , figure 1, very condensed between 0-100s,not so condensed after that. but in the linear x-axis, it's not obvious to figure the condensed fact out.
So I would like to customize the x-axis to zoom in some part and zoom out some other part. for example, here, to zoom in the 0-100s which may take almost half the axis, and zoom out 100-1750s  for the other half axis.

Following figure 2 is a example of what I mean the 'customized' x-axis, which have [0.5s,1.3s,5s,10s,20s,30s,60s,2m,5m,10m,8h] on axis.

[image: figure1]

[image: figure2]

Sorry that I'm new here that can't attach the figure to the chatbox directly.

Answer (score 0):

**Different parts at different 'zoom' levels**

You describe that you want your figure to be zoomed in between 0 and 100, and zoomed out between 100 to 1750. For this, you can create something similar to the 'broken axis' example [available in the `matplotlib` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html), but let me show you how you could apply it to your dataset.

First, let me generate a fake dataset that sort of looks like yours, as you have not made your dataset available.

```
large_peak = 10 * np.random.randn(100) + 10
other_data = 2000 * np.random.uniform(size=10)
data = np.concatenate((large_peak, other_data))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bins = np.arange(0, np.max(data), 20)
ax.hist(data, bins=bins, density=True)
```

This produces the following figure:

[image: histogram with a large peak around x = 0]

Now, to create this figure with a broken axis, we split the figure up in two subplots, plot the same data in these subplots, hide the line between the subplots, make the subplots connect, and set their x limits correctly.

```
# sharey to have the same y axis limits, wspace=0 to make the axes connect
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0})

# x limits of the axes
xlim1 = (0, 100)
xlim2 = (100, 1750)

# calculate the histogram bin width such that it is equal for both axes
# we choose 50 bins per axis, you can change this value
bins1 = np.arange(xlim1[0], xlim1[1] + 1, np.diff(xlim1) / 50)
bins2 = np.arange(xlim2[0], xlim2[1] + 1, np.diff(xlim2) / 50)

# plot the same data in both axes
ax1.hist(data, bins=bins1, density=True)
ax2.hist(data, bins=bins2, density=True)

# hide the spines and ticks
ax1.spines.right.set_visible(False)
ax2.spines.left.set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', left=False)

# set the x limits
ax1.set_xlim(xlim1)
ax2.set_xlim(xlim2)
```

This produces the following figure:

[image: histogram with two different 'zoom' levels on the x axis]

Now, you can see that the left half of the figure is zoomed in, while the right half is zoomed out. You might want to clarify this change of axes, for example using a dotted gray line through the middle.

```
# add line to indicate the change in x scale
ax1.axvline(xlim1[1], clip_on=False, color='gray', linestyle=':')
```

[image: histogram with two different 'zoom' levels on the x axis, and a dotted line in the middle to indicate the change in zoom levels]

**Log scale?**

The title of your question suggests that you do not want to use a log scale for your figure, and you give an example of a figure with a different x axis (the figure you call "figure2"). However, this figure's x axis has a log scale, its ticks have just been placed unconventionally (to indicate peaks in the data). See the following figure, where I have used the difference between the '60' tick (1 minute) and the '10m' tick (10 minutes) to find the size of the decades in the x axis:

[image: highlighted log scale]

Clearly, you can see that the x axis in this figure is actually scaled logarithmically. You can place the ticks at different locations using the [`ax.set_xticks()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html) method, also in a log scaled figure.

Comment: Thank you soooo much ,with you anwser I finally find what I want is actually a scaled logarithmical figure... :-) really appreciate!

Comment: If you have more strange nonlinear axis scaling, look into https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xscale.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create the second example, which uses a log scale. A [custom formatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html) can be created to display a value for an x tick to either seconds, minutes or hours.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter, FuncFormatter

import numpy as np

minutes = 60
hours = 60 * minutes

def hms_formatter(x, pos):
    if x < 120:
        return f'{x:g}'
    elif x < 120 * minutes:
        return f'{x / minutes:g}m'
    else:
        return f'{x / hours:g}h'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks([.5, 1.3, 5, 10, 20, 30, 60, 2*minutes, 5*minutes, 10*minutes, 8*hours])
ax.set_xticks([i for i in range(1, 20)] + [i for i in range(20, 120, 10)]
              + [i * minutes for i in range(1, 20)] + [i * minutes for i in range(20, 120, 10)]
              + [i * hours for i in range(1, 10)],
              minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(hms_formatter))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
x = np.logspace(0, np.log10(8 * hours), 200)
y = np.random.normal(0.1, 1, 200).cumsum() + 5
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.margins(x=0)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: logscale for seconds, minutes, hours]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I returned with the followings,anything not mentioned in your answer?                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError: formatter argument should be instance of matplotlib.ticker.Formatter

Comment: I edited the code to use FuncFormatter to make it also work for older matplotlib versions. (If possible, you're strongly encouraged to upgrade.)

Comment: Thanks JohanC, I find a interesting question, in this way (x = np.logspace(0, np.log10(8 * hours), 200)) , the starting point of x-axis will always be 1 and can't reach to 0. I tried to use float('-inf') instead of 0, but with an error.  How the picture I posted reached 0?

Comment: I think they didn't reached 0 , just some point between 0 and 1

Comment: With a log scale, zero will be at minus infinity, so impossible to show. Also, putting a very small number (say `1e-10`) on plot would stretch everything too much.  To put zero on such an axis, there is the `semilog` scale which draws the part near zero in linear scale.  Matplotlib also has a `symlog` scale which draws negative values via the log of their absolute value and uses semilog around zero. [tutorial example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-scales-scales-py)